# 2004 Chevy Malibu Classic Acceleration & starting problems

Tags: engine, chevrolet, starting, malibu

I was riding along and my 2004 Chevy Malibu Classic stopped accelerating. I was pressing the gas but it wouldn't go any faster. I coasted off the highway and turned it off, then I started it back up and shut it off as I called for assistance. When I tried to start it back again it would not crank that time

A few days before I could pull up to a stop sign or red light and it would make this loud rattling noise but when I take off it would stop. I was told to replace my harmonic balancer.

Comment: Did you replace your harmonic balancer?

Comment: When you say, "It would not crank that time" ... do you mean you would turn the key and nothing happened? Or do you mean it would not fire up? If it is turning over but not firing, it's probably a fuel issue (considering the diagnostics you've given thus far) ... I'd have the fuel pump checked.

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: And not follow up to comments. Without more information it can't be answered in a definitive way.